# Angular Universal app running in shared hosting

Tags: node.js, angular, shared-hosting, angular-universal

So I have created an angular universal app and I have successfully deployed it in Heroku and it's running great. I would like to know if it is possible I can run it in a shared hosting. More specifically I have A2Hosting shared plan which supports node.js. More over which commands should I execute in the server in order to start the node server? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think that the question can be extrapolated to shared hosting in general? It's `npm i & npm start` everywhere - unless it isn't. Read the manual https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts .

Comment: I don't understand which files should I copy in order to run the app, or which commands should I execute after I deploy the app. I was using angular with .netcore 2 previously and I was just coping the dist folder without and node.js server inside.

Comment: This isn't specific to hosting but to running Node project in general. If you need to run it on another machine, you git-clone or copy it without npm_modules and run `npm i` and `npm start`.